# Asterisk Real time does not perform register with SIP TRUNK provider

Tags: asterisk, sip, dynamic

I am using astersik real time (dynamic). I have entered my SIP trunk details into the sippeers tables.

However, the sip trunk does not perform a register with the SIP TRUNK providers servers as it would if wrote it in sip.conf manually as

register => username:password@

I use the recommended sippeers table as describe at the asterisk documentation:

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/SIP+Realtime,+MySQL+table+structure

I know that the sip trunk is not being registered because :

1. i do not see it as registered when i do a sip show registry on the asterisk CLI
2. When i attempt to make a call, asterisk throws a forbidden error.
3. It however recognises my sip trunk as a peer.
4. When i manually write the entries into the sip.conf file, it all works. i.e: register statement and sip trunk peer description.

Any inputs will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not gonna work. http://lists.digium.com/pipermail/asterisk-users/2009-November/241425.html

> Use #exec directive to execute external script which retrieves registration
>   data from DB, and outputs correct registration string as text.
>
> Do not forget to enable #exec in asterisk.conf
>
> You will need to do sip reload each time you change registration settings.
>
> With reload you will lose all existing registrations and all previously
>   registered devices will be unreachable till they register again.